# jQuery: textboxes in dialog window not working

Tags: jquery, dialog

i'm having a problem with the jquery dialog widget:
i put a form with textboxes and combos inside a jquery dialog - when showing it up, all textboxes are not editable/clickable at all - all i can do is changing the comboboxes.
seems like a bug to me :/
any ideas how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: it would help if u can post a bit of the cde to exactly pin point what the error could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, you may have a `z-index` issue. Check what Firebug says and make sure that you don't have an element over your textboxes.

Comment: yes i could fix it by setting the form's z-index but it's not the perfect solution. because when having another form below the dialog, that form will also overlap the modal dialog :/ so i guess it's a bug in the dialog widget. i'll try asking in the jquery forum - thanks!